# How to redirect url by query parameters in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm using `ngRoute` in `angularjs` to delegate different html templates, eg:

```
phonecatApp.config(['$routeProvider',
  function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
      when('/phones', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/phone-list.html',
        controller: 'PhoneListCtrl'
      }).
      when('/cars', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/car-detail.html',
        controller: 'CarDetailCtrl'
      });

    //many more routes
  }]);
```

Problem: I want to have a common url, like `localhost/my-app?myparam=Nokia`.

I want to compare the `myparam` to a mapping table. If the param name is a phone company, I want to delegate to `/phones`. If it's a car company, I want to delegate to `/cars`, etc. You get the idea.

Also I have to rewrite the url as follows: `localhost/myapp/phones?myparam=Nokia`. Thereby the ngRoute would automatically catch the correct template and controller.

Question: how can I intercept the initial loading, and redirect based on the url param?

Sidenote: I cannot rewrite the routeProvider config eg by using a different plugin like `angular-ui-router`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you might want to take a step back and reconsider why you're trying to tackle it this way but given your constraints, your best bet may be to have a service that returns the correct URL and call it from the controller:

```
phonecatApp.controller("trafficCtrl", function ($routeParams,trafficService,$location) {
    if ($routeParams.myparam) {
        var destination = trafficService.getDestination($routeParams.myparam);
        $location.path(destination);
    }
})
.service("trafficService", function () {
    this.getDestination = function (paramValue) {
        switch(paramValue) {
            case "Nokia":
                return "/phones";
            case "Ford":
                return "some/car/url";
            // etc...
        }
    }
});
```

Also, you have to add the following (generic) route to the provider:

```
$routeProvider.when("/", {
      template: '',
      controller: 'trafficController'
});
```

Comment: But would this approach automatically link `templates` to `controllers`?  That's what I like most about ngroute, explicit linking them together and invoke them just by the url path.

Comment: @membersound - yes it would. Let's say that myparam is "Nokia". It would redirect the user to partials/phone-list.html at which time $routeProvider would realize it and know to use the corresponding template and controller

Comment: So I'd have to keep my `.config` of ngRoute, and additionally use your servicecontroller approach to call these routes? If yes, how can I ensure that your controller intercepts before the ngRoutes are evaluated?

Comment: And moreover: shouldn't I return `case "Nokia": return "/phones";` in the switch statements?

Comment: Correct, keep your .config and then call the service. You shouldn't need to worry about ngRoute doing any unintended evaluating because you'll direct all traffic the the trafficCtrl controller first, which will then forward them to the correct path, at which point ngRoute kicks in.

Comment: And you are correct regarding returning just "/phones" - that was an error on my part. I've updated my example now

Comment: Thanks, will try this tomorrow and let you know.

Comment: It took me a lot of trial and error, but I managed to get [a working Plunker of this here](http://plnkr.co/edit/Y7BTWwdcOi2UHVE2ti2l?p=preview).

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is right solution.. But you can create a new route `/myapp` .. Write a controller and redirect using `$location` service .. After finding the query para value using `$location.query()`  and redirect it accordingly

Comment: Hm, is that advisable? Especially from performance point of view?

Comment: I am a newbie .. so my knowledge is limited  but I don' t think performance will impact that much but if you are redirecting for a particular route.

Comment: you can also write it in`angular.run`  but i wont recommend it as `run` will run before controller for every view loaded. so if u open other url's which don't need redirection the code will run but if every url user accesses need to be redirected then u can consider run as it will load before any controller or directives. you can keep the redirection code in different module and import it to tour original one and redirect it in angular run so that the url will be intercepted before loading of other elements. (my guess is that performance will not be impacted.. but you need to check about it)

Comment: I only need the redirect to be run once on first access. During navigation on my page, it should not run again.

Answer (score 0):

If we make it a REST call like **/my-app/Nokia** or **my-app/Samsung** instead of Query params, I think we can dynamically route it in the config itself.

```
phonecatApp.config(['$routeProvider',
  function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
      when('/my-app/:myparam', {
        templateUrl: function(params){
         return TemplateMappingFunction(params.myparam) +'.html'
    },
        controller: function(params){
         return ControllerMappingFunction(params.myparam)
    }
      })

    //many more routes
  }]);
```

For example,

- if the URL is **/my-app/Nokia**, TemplateMappingFunction(Nokia) will return partials/phone-list.html',
- if the URL is **/my-app/Nokia**, TemplateMappingFunction(Nokia) will return partials/phone-list.html',
- if the URL is **/my-app/BMW**, TemplateMappingFunction(BMW) will return partials/car-details.html',

**Query Param approach**

```
 phonecatApp.config(['$routeProvider',
          function($routeProvider) {
           /* Function to retrieve Query parameters*/
           function getParameterByName(name) {
                name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\]");
                var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
                    results = regex.exec(location.search);
                return results === null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
            }

            $routeProvider.
              when('/my-app', {
                templateUrl: TemplateMappingFunction(getParameterByName('myparam'))
            },
                controller: ControllerMappingFunction(getParameterByName('myparam'))
            }
              })

            //many more routes
          }]);
```

So, if the URL is **localhost/my-app?myparam=Nokia**, then TemplateMappingFunction('Nokia') will return 'partials/phone-list.html'

Comment: Great approach, but unfortunately I have no impact on the url, so I have to stick to evaluate by query param(s).

Comment: In that case the above code (Query Param approach) should do the job.